# How to disable specific href link through buttonclick event

Tags: javascript, html, html-tbody

I have multiple tables wher each row is defined by an ID and a class. The words in each row are actually `href links`. I have one button with id `testbuttonba`. If `testbuttonba` is clicked, I want the following to occur:

1) `href` for ID `table1` to be disable.

2) `href` for ID `table2` and `table3` to still be enabled.

My code below does not work (all links are still enabled after clicking):

**HTML**

```
<body>
<button class="btnba" id="testbtnba" onclick="function2()">BA</button>

    /* 1st Table */
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><font size="1">Capability Group</font></th>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="showdoc.html"><font size="1"><strong>A. Organisational Content</strong></font></a></td>
           </tr>
    </table>

    /* 2nd Table */
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><font size="1">Capability Group</font></th>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="table2">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="showpdf.html"><font size="1"><strong>B. Basic Requirements</strong></font></a></td>
           </tr>
    </table>

    /* 3rd Table */
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><font size="1">Capability Group</font></th>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="table3">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="showexcel.html"><font size="1"><strong>C. Rules and Regulations</strong></font></a></td>
           </tr>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    /*diasble the first link - not working*/
    function function2() {
        document.getElementById("table1").href = "#";
    }
    return false;
</script>
```

Comment: you dont have tbody closing tags ?

Comment: `getElementById()` will return the element `<tbody>`, which does not have a href attribute.  The simplest way to fix your issue would be to set the link href value to nothing, or `#`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove the `href` on the `<a/>` (at least without storing in some way). You can create a toggle that will determine whether or not `Event.preventDefault()` will be called when the button is clicked.

This will do the trick:

```js
let linkActive = false;
disableToggle = () => {
  linkActive = !linkActive;
}

document.querySelector('#table1 tr td a').onclick = ev => {
  if (linkActive) {
    ev.preventDefault('sd');
  }
};
```

```css
.smallFont {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btnba" id="testbtnba" onclick="disableToggle()">BA</button>
<br/> /* 1st Table */
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="smallFont">Capability Group</span>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="showdoc.html">
          <span class="smallFont"><strong>A. Organisational Content</strong></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

/* 2nd Table */
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="smallFont">Capability Group</span>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="showpdf.html">
          <span class="smallFont"><strong>B. Basic Requirements</strong></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

/* 3rd Table */
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="smallFont">Capability Group</span>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="table3">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="showexcel.html">
          <span class="smallFont"><strong>C. Rules and Regulations</strong></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The reason it does not work in your snippet above is only because your selector doesn't select the `<a/>` element, doing this will rectify that:

```js
function function2() {
  document.querySelector("#table1 tr td a").setAttribute('href', '#');
}
```

```css
.smallFont {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btnba" id="testbtnba" onclick="disableToggle()">BA</button>
<br/> /* 1st Table */
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="smallFont">Capability Group</span>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="showdoc.html">
          <span class="smallFont"><strong>A. Organisational Content</strong></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

/* 2nd Table */
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="smallFont">Capability Group</span>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="showpdf.html">
          <span class="smallFont"><strong>B. Basic Requirements</strong></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

/* 3rd Table */
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="smallFont">Capability Group</span>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="table3">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="showexcel.html">
          <span class="smallFont"><strong>C. Rules and Regulations</strong></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Keep in mind, that there is no way to re-enable the link using the code in this way :o

Update: Replaced the `<font/>` tags with some CSS. The `<font/>` element is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).
Hope that helps,

Comment: Do not keep obsolete elements in the code. Correct and let OP know that.

Comment: @musa I have updated my answer to remove the `<front/>` element as it is obsolete and may not work in modern browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: @LGSon, thank you for notifying me, I completely overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

Your script is grabbing the wrong element. `document.getElementById("table1")` returns a `tbody` element, which does not have an `href`attribute on it.

You need to add an id to the `a` element, like: `<a id="some-id">`

Then, use it to grab the link and change the href: `document.getElementById("some-id").href = "#";`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the anchor tag in element with id table1, and disable it like below.

```
function function2() {
    var a = document.querySelector('#table1 a');
    a.setAttribute('href','#');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please change the function 
  function function2() {

            document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = "#";
        }
```

result of this code document.getElementById("table1") is tbody tag and then you should find the tag a in this tag then disable the href .
i hope my answer give you an idea .